# Transforming Sync functions to Async

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, .when

I am trying to make a series of synchronous calls into asynchronous, and I'm using when...done...  I'm new at this stuff, but from all the reading I've been doing on this subject the last two days, my code below should work.  Well, it does work, but not exactly in the way that I meant for it.

In my test code below I make five calls, and each one would take a different amount of time (in my example, it's based on the length of the string... 1/2 a second per character).  My expectation was that the calls that took less time (i.e. the shorter length strings in my example) would complete first I fire off all five calls quickly, and would expect the results to be displayed in order of shorter execution to longer execution.

Here's my code:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Chrysler", "Volvo", "BMW", "GT"];
loopAll(cars);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Start!<br>";
function loopAll(array) {
  for (var i in array) {
   $.when( encapsulate(array[i]) ).done( printIt );
  }
  function encapsulate(name){
    var a = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){pause(name.length*500);a.resolve(name);}, 0);
    return a;
  }
}
function printIt(name){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += name + "<br>";
}
function pause(ms) {
  ms += new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date() < ms){}
}
```

Each of the elements in the array get printed, and I can see them popping on the display one by one.  However, they seem to be synchronous in that they are being displayed in the original order of the array, and the pause is occurring between each of the displayed elements.  However, my expectation was that the shorter executing functions finishing (and displaying) sooner than the longer ones.

Note: I am NOT trying to sort the array.  My intent is to fire off multiple calls and let the shorter executing ones finish first, and not sequentially.  I'm using the array of strings only as an example.

Comment: `setTimeout` at `encapsulate` appear set to `0` ?

Comment: @guest271314, yes.  Reading on this site that's what I read as a good method for launching that code immediately, effectively creating a new thread just for that code.

Comment: _"In my test code below I make five calls, and each one would take a different amount of time (in my example, it's based on the length of the string... 1/2 a second per character)."_ ? If each `setTimeout` `duration`  set to `0` for each `$.Deferred` created at `encapsulate` , length of string _not_ utilized for each `duration` of `setTimeout` called at `encapsulate`  ? , instead `0` appear set at each iteration ?

Answer (score 1):

The timeout block isn't really doing anything in this scenario.  It will immediately execute its function block.

JavaScript is single threaded, by using that homebrewed 'pause' method you are effectively blocking the thread and causing each loop to be executed synchronously.

If you have some synchronous code, and an asynchronous alternative isn't available, you may be able to use web workers to shift them off of the main thread.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: +1; `setTimeout` does not create "a new execution thread," like you said in your other comment; it simply schedules a function to be run some time in the future. When run, the function will still be run on the single thread, and will still block execution.

Comment: I definitely am unsure on how to do this, but I can vouch that setTimeout does not block execution.  If a person were to run this code they would see that the "print" statement right after the loop call executes right away.  In other words, the "start!" message is displaying immediately, even though it is after all the looping code.

Comment: `setTimeout` can defer code execution until the next tick (or some later date), but I assure you that the code inside still blocks executes synchronously. See my answer for an example.

Comment: So I guess I'm learning that setTimeout isn't really adding another thread.  And even though it isn't blocking execution, the queue of setTimeout events are run sequentially once the main thread completes.  Hmmm... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> In my test code below I make five calls, and each one would take a
>   different amount of time (in my example, it's based on the length of
>   the string... 1/2 a second per character).

At

```
setTimeout(function(){pause(name.length*500);a.resolve(name);}, 0);
```

the `duration` appear to be set to `0` for each `$.Deferred()` object created ? Not certain about expected result of `pause` ?

> My expectation was that the calls that took less time (i.e. the
>   shorter length strings in my example) would complete first I fire off
>   all five calls quickly, and would expect the results to be displayed
>   in order of shorter execution to longer execution.

try setting `duration` of `setTimeout` to `name.length*500`

---

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Chrysler", "Volvo", "BMW", "GT"];
loopAll(cars);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Start!<br>";
function loopAll(array) {
  for (var i in array) {
   $.when( encapsulate(array[i]) ).done( printIt );
  }
  function encapsulate(name){
    var a = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function(){a.resolve(name);}, name.length*500);
    return a;
  }
}
function printIt(name){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += name + "<br>";
}

// function pause(ms) {
//  ms += new Date().getTime();
//  while (new Date() < ms){}
// }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: You have an unnecessary semi-colon in the timeout block.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not explaining the intent of my code.  In the actual case I will be using, I do not know how long that function call will take.  I simply simulated a random duration call by using the length of the string.  In summary, I need to loop through some objects in an array and run some processing on them asynchronously, but the function call I am making is not asynchronous.

Comment: @tagale Yes. Can indicate where _"I simply simulated a random duration call by using the length of the string"_ set at OP ? Appear to be set to `0` at each iteration of `cars` array ?

Comment: Also, the setTimeout value of zero is not what is making the code execute synchronously.  In fact, if I increase that value it just further delays execution of anything in that loop.  Reminder: I'm using setTimeout as a way of starting a new execution thread, not to add any timing to the execution.

Comment: @tagale Not certain about requirement ? Is requirement to utilize `Promise` object to return value, or utilize `setTimeout` within synchronous processes ? Can describe expected result of _"using setTimeout as a way of starting a new execution thread"_ ?

Comment: @tagale _"My expectation was that the calls that took less time (i.e. the shorter length strings in my example) would complete first I fire off all five calls quickly, and would expect the results to be displayed in order of shorter execution to longer execution."_ ? Tried `js` at stacksnippets ? ,  expected results returned ?

Comment: @guest271314, my real requirement was purely to launch all of the commands for each item in the array, and execute the loop quickly.  And I did accomplish that, so I really don't need to work the issue any more.  The loop does launch each of the commands and exits the loop, placing each of those commands in the js queue.  However, I was surprised that the order those were executed was still sequential, as opposed to in parallel, and I'm finding out that it is because JS isn't truly multithreaded, rather it's just queueing things for execution when time is available.

Answer (score 0):

The code you listed is a bit of a red herring; the problem, it turns out, is in the statement "I am trying to make a series of synchronous calls into asynchronous." In most JavaScript environments, this simply isn't possible.

JS environments are generally single threaded, so even if you use `setTimeout` to schedule code execution for some time in the future, that code will *still* block the thread. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/r4ct92c5/) for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/r4ct92c5/

Unless you use something like [Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/) (in the browser) or [external processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), [fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers), or [native addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) in Node, you can't execute JS code asynchronously.